# SpringBoot not deploying on weblogic

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to deploy simple springboot app on weblogic. but see some error.

my java classes are

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringBootHelloWorld</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>SpringBootHelloWorld</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java class

```
package com.javainuse;
import javafx.application.Application;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootHelloWorldApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

and this is my TestController class.

```
package com.javainuse.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("/welcome.html")
    public ModelAndView firstPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("welcome");
    }

}
```

I get below error

```
Caused By: com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed to load java type corresponding to e=web-fragment@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.getPojoBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:371)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:326)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineTypeForGlobalElement(UnmarshalResult.java:336)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.determineRootType(UnmarshalResult.java:317)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshalResult.java:168)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am using weblogic 12 with java8.

Please assist with this issue since I tried all the options already provided and it is not working. I get this error when server tries to deploy this application.

Comment: You can not deploy normal spring boot application directly, you need to create some weblogic specific stuff.. Follow this blog: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-weblogic

Comment: Thank you Yogi.
I could resolve it after I posted it here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Discovery what was it that you did from the docs.spring.io blog that fixed this for you? I'm having the same issues but can't figure it out...